# ORA-02298 Parent Keys Not Found?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've been stuck on this for ages as every time I try it - it comes up with the following error: Cannot Validate - parent keys not found.

Here's the code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVI20.jpg):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVI20.jpg]

I can create the Primary Key in the Employees table and assign it to EmployeeId. But when trying to add that as a foreign key in the WorkPackages table (using the code below)

```
ALTER TABLE WORKPACKAGES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEEID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEEID);
```

it keeps on coming up with the validation error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It probably means you have rows in your child table with one or several EMPLOYEEID that are not found in the parent table. Try updating the child rows, or adding the parent rows and create the foreign key again.

Answer (score 23):

```
ALTER TABLE WORKPACKAGES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEEID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEEID);
```

When this key is enforced, Oracle checks that all employeeid present in Workpackages table is present in Employees table.

Your options:

Find the [offending keys by running](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc485/3)

```
SELECT employeeid
FROM   workpackages
WHERE  employeeid NOT IN (SELECT employeeid
                          FROM   employees);
```

and then insert them into the employee table.

Another option is to use [NOVALIDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11538) so that existing data isn't checked, but any new inserts/updates will be validated. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb122f) for demo on this.

Comment: / Thanks very much. I will have to insert all of my data first however and then add the foreign keys since it will just come up with a validation error if I add the foreign keys first and the data second.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem puzzled me a lot when I am trying to add constraint  foreign key.Now I have made it.I key in some values in the father table.For example:

alter table A
  add constraint A_01 foreign key (CODE)  references B(CODE);
I key in :insert into B(CODE) values(0);
and then it works!