# ORA-02298 - Parent keys not found when enable constraint

Tags: oracle, constraints, data-migration

I have a migration script in between 2 different schema database. The script does 3 things:

1. Disable constraint
2. Insert record from old schema to new schema
3. Enable constraint

During enable constraint, it encouter `ORA-02298 - Parent keys not found`: at the following 2 tables:

```
ALTER TABLE COUNTRY ENABLE CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_FK1;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ENABLE CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK7;
```

Anything went wrong in the table structure definition of these 2 tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-02298 Parent Keys Not Found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732053/ora-02298-parent-keys-not-found)

Comment: it's different, this error i hit during enable constraint

Comment: Nothing wrong with *structure definition*, but with data. There are *detail* records that doesn't have matching *master* ones (for example, it says that employee Littlefoot works in department 10, while table DEPARTMENTS doesn't have a row with department = 10).

Comment: it's not different; when you're enabling the constraint it checks the data conforms to it. that error means that it can't enforce the constraint with the data existing as it does.

Comment: ok, let take table COUNTRY as an example, the FK linked to table REGION.REGION_CODE. So you are saying the same code found in COUNTRY but not in REGION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are migrating detail records without ensuring that **all** the foreign key values are present in the referenced tables. If this is the case then you need to migrate records from `REGION@SOURCE_DB` into `REGION@TARGET_DB` before you migrate the `COUNTRY` records.